# How to join/write two pandas dataframes to a single file

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am reading in a CSV file to a pandas data frame for scientific analysis/processing. I create a second "identical" data frame. I do the analysis/processing on the second data frame. I'd like to return the data to a CSV file with the two data frames "side by side" so the original data can be compared with the processed data.

Input code from file:

```
reader = pd.read_csv(Filename1, sep=none, engine='python')
df = pd.DataFrame(reader)
dg = pd.DataFrame(reader)
```

I do processing on `dg`. Now, I want to write `df` and `dg` (each data frame consisting of the same number of columns) to a CSV file so that each line of the CSV file looks like this:

*(df Col1), (df Col2), (df Col3), (dg Col1), (dg Col2), (dg Col3)*

How do I create a new data frame which joins `df` and `dg` together 'side by side'?

Expecting to write the resulting data frame to a second CSV file (Filename2) with the following statement (assuming that `di` is the two data frames joined together).

```
di.head(EndFile).to_csv(Filename2, sep='\t', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: `df.add_prefix('df ').join(dg.add_prefix('dg '))`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) like this:

```
di = pd.merge(df, dg, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('_df', '_dg'))
```

Comment: Thanks - if the columns of the two dataframes don't have header names do I need the "suffix" qualifier?

Comment: I do not really know, how you could even make a data frame without column names. That is very unusual. I expected your data frames `df` and `dg` to have the same number of columns and these columns to be named the same. If not, please, update your question and provide rows examples of both data frames, e. g. `df.head()` and `dg.head()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try a simple merge than save to csv.

```
import pandas as pd
dict1 = {'a':[2,3,4],'b':[4,5,6]}
dict2 = {'a':[7,5,6],'b':[6,8,10]}
first = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
second = pd.DataFrame(dict2)

first
    a   b
0   2   4
1   3   5
2   4   6

second
    a   b
0   7   6
1   5   8
2   6   10

first.merge(second, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('_first','_second'))

        a_first b_first a_second b_second
0       2       4       7        6
1       3       5       5        8
2       4       6       6        10

combined_df = first.merge(second, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('_first','_second'))

combined_df.to_csv(filename)
```

Comment: you could also do df.join(dg, lsuffix='_df', rsuffix='_dg')